# Apache pig on windows gives "hadoop-config.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command" error when running "pig -x local"

Tags: windows, hadoop, apache-pig

If you are stuck at running Apache Pig on windows due to an error like

```
hadoop-2.4.0\bin\hadoop-config.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

though you are having Hadoop running perfectly on windows

Comment: thanks for the info. Can I know which version of PIG you used? Did you download the package or built it from source on Windows? In both cases, can you please provide a link?

Comment: I downloaded it from [link](http://mirror.fibergrid.in/apache/pig/pig-0.16.0/pig-0.16.0-src.tar.gz)

Comment: Nice to see that you try to help others with your solution! For ease of site use, please do the following next time: When you ask the question, check the box: "Answer your own question", that will give you the opportunity to add the answer directly. -- I don't know whether you can add an answer already now, so I will split the answer and question for you.

Answer (score 3):

Answer, which was originally added by the asker inside the quesiton.

These steps may help you.

**Troubleshooting steps**

- open the file **pig.cmd** in any editor like notpad / notepad++
- look for the line `set HADOOP_BIN_PATH=%HADOOP_HOME%\bin`
- replace this with `set HADOOP_BIN_PATH=%HADOOP_HOME%\libexec`

What we did was that **hadoop-config.cmd** file was not being found by pig so we pointed it with the correct one. You may first find where the **hadoop-config.cmd** file is and replace it with appropriate path. This was what my  hadoop-2.4.0 was having.