# xmx1000m is not recognized as an internal or external command: pig on windows

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to setup pig on windows 7. I already have hadoop 2.7 single node cluster running on windows 7.

To setup pig, I have taken following steps as of now.

1. Downloaded the tar: http://mirror.metrocast.net/apache/pig/
2. Extracted tar to: C:\Users\zeba\Desktop\pig
3. Have set the Environment (User) Variable to:

   PIG_HOME = C:\Users\zeba\Desktop\pig

   PATH = C:\Users\zeba\Desktop\pig\bin

   PIG_CLASSPATH = C:\Users\zeba\Desktop\hadoop\conf
4. Also changed HADOOP_BIN_PATH in pig.cmd to %HADOOP_HOME%\libexec as suggested by ([Apache pig on windows gives "hadoop-config.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command" error when running "pig -x local"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183947/apache-pig-on-windows-gives-hadoop-config-cmd-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal)) as was getting the same error
5. When I enter pig, I encounter the following error:

> xmx1000m is not recognized as an internal or external command

Please help!

Comment: https://qnalist.com/questions/5661317/error-with-pig-installation-testing-xmx1000m-is-not-a-recognized-command

Comment: @philantrovert Thanks for the help, it motivated me to try the latest release pig-0.17.0 and the error went away. But I ran into another issue where pig.cmd complaint: "could not find or load main class c:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\lib\tools.jar

Answer (score 0):

The error went away by installing pig-0.17.0. I was working with pig-0.16.0 previously.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got it. I changed HADOOP BIN PATH in pig.cmd to "HADOOP_HOME%\hadoop-2.9.2\libexec",  as you can see "hadoop-2.9.2" is a subfile where "libexec" from my hadoop version is located..

Answer (score 0):

Fix your "HADOOP_HOME" according to given image don't provide bin path only provide hadoop path.
[image: hadoop path image]